# How to go back from dolphin file manager to nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, nautilus, kde

Currently, find my sweet spot between gnome and KDE on ubuntu. Right now I've messed up, KDE icon pack is not supported on Wayland and dolphin file manager in default because I tried to switch from ubuntu to Kubuntu desktop to use KDE plasma. Now I don't know where to go. Can I reset gnome settings like back to start? something like that. If anyone can help me.

I'm a machine learning student, and I don't want to switch from ubuntu because libraries I'll be using in the future will have more support on ubuntu as compared to arch or Debian. What options do I have with ubuntu? I want it to be clean and powerful.

Comment: I'm unsure of your issue, myself I like & have installed multiple desktops so am used to dealing with issues with multiple installed (issues usually appear when you have more than just two though). Are you selecting which (DE or desktop) you want to use at login? Once logged in, I can use `dolphin`, `nautilus`, `pcmanfm-qt`, `thunar`, `caja` without issue, selecting which I want to use when I open it. If the KDE 'default' icon pack doesn't play well, change it.  Sorry I don't understand your issue.  FYI: *multiple DEs isn't a good place to be if new to GNU/Linux; it does complicate things*

Comment: Yes! I was having an issue with DE. I've switched back to nautilus. Thanks for commenting and increasing my knowledge.